# ggplot boxplot customize varwidth

Tags: r, ggplot2, width, customization, boxplot

[image]I have been using the following code to produce the attached output:

```
  geom_boxplot(varwidth=TRUE)+
  ylab("AbstConc") +
  xlab("Lexical Class") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Character Length of Word >= 6"))+
  scale_fill_hue(labels = c("Yes", "No"))+
  hrbrthemes::theme_ipsum()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

As can be seen, the width for certain boxplots is too narrow. The documentation states that one can adjust the width using weights:
"if FALSE (default) make a standard box plot. If TRUE, boxes are drawn with widths proportional to the square-roots of the number of observations in the groups (possibly weighted, using the weight aesthetic)"

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to figure out how to change the width using the weight aesthetic.
The data can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14KeacZya7f6wvH0B7lVOKD7aLriAfH1N/view?usp=drive_link

Thank you for your help:)

Comment: It looks like you forgot to copy the first line of your code into the question. If you share a sample of data using `dput()` and add it to the question, you're more likely to get a response (instead of asking people to download files from unknown links...)